# Set the background color for a fixed range of cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have VBA code in an Excel spreadsheet. It is used to set the font and background color of a cell based on the value in that cell. I am doing it in VBA instead of "Conditional Formatting" because I have more than 3 conditions. The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range, d As Range, fc As Long, bc As Long, bf As Boolean
Set d = Intersect(Range("A:K"), Target)
If d Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each c In d
    If c >= Date And c <= Date + 5 Then
        fc = 2: fb = True: bc = 3
    Else
        Select Case c
            Case "ABC"
                fc = 2: fb = True: bc = 5
            Case 1, 3, 5, 7
                fc = 2: fb = True: bc = 1
            Case "D", "E", "F"
                fc = 2: fb = True: bc = 10
            Case "1/1/2009"
                fc = 2: fb = True: bc = 45
            Case "Long string"
                fc = 3: fb = True: bc = 1
            Case Else
                fc = 1: fb = False: bc = xlNone
        End Select
    End If
    c.Font.ColorIndex = fc
    c.Font.Bold = fb
    c.Interior.ColorIndex = bc
    c.Range("A1:D1").Interior.ColorIndex = bc
Next
End Sub
```

The problem is in the "c.Range" line. It always uses the current cell as "A" and then goes four cells to the right. I want it to start in the "real" cell "A" of the current row and go to the "real" cell "D" of the current row. Basically, I want a fixed range and not a dynamic one.

Comment: Just to verify, I assume you are worried about the allowed number of conditions because this will be delivered to more than just users with xl2007?

Comment: We are using Excel 2003 which appears to only allow 3 conditions. The user had 6 conditions to test against including the date range which they couldn't get to work in the wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `c.Range("A1:D1")` has its own relative range.
One solution is to use the worksheet's range property instead.
I added two lines towards the top (`#added`), and changed one at the bottom (`#changed`).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range, d As Range, fc As Long, bc As Long, bf As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet ''#added

Set d = Intersect(Range("A:K"), Target).Cells
Set ws = d.Worksheet ''#added
If d Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each c In d.Cells
    If c >= Date And c <= Date + 5 Then
        fc = 2: bf = True: bc = 3
    Else
        Select Case c.Value
            Case "ABC"
                fc = 2: bf = True: bc = 5
            Case 1, 3, 5, 7
                fc = 2: bf = True: bc = 1
            Case "D", "E", "F"
                fc = 2: bf = True: bc = 10
            Case "1/1/2009"
                fc = 2: bf = True: bc = 45
            Case "Long string"
                fc = 3: bf = True: bc = 1
            Case Else
                fc = 1: bf = False: bc = xlNone
        End Select
    End If
    c.Font.ColorIndex = fc
    c.Font.Bold = bf
    c.Interior.ColorIndex = bc
    ws.Cells(c.Row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = bc ''#changed
    ws.Cells(c.Row, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = bc ''#added
    ws.Cells(c.Row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = bc ''#added
    ws.Cells(c.Row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = bc ''#added
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: But this sets A through D of the "first" row (A1:D1). I want A through D of the "current" row. If I enter "5/1/2010" in cell E7, I want A7 through D7 to change. If I enter "5/1/2010" in cell c99, I want A99 through D99 to change. Basically, the first four cells of the current column.

Comment: @Count: great catch. Fixed that problem. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Since you showed me that "c.Row" is the number of the current row, I combined the last four rows into one:
ws.Range("A" & c.Row & ":D" & c.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = bc

Many thanks.